# creating functions to calculate the technical error and the coefficient of variation of the error

Tags: r

I have this equation (which can be accessed through [this link](http://i39.tinypic.com/110vfk6.jpg)):

[image]

I would like to create two functions by using r. The first one is by using the first equation provided.

The second function is to create a mathematical formula in which the first function is substituted. Here is the formula:

(http://i43.tinypic.com/b6vq5j.jpg)

THis is the head of my data: (data_1)

```
  sex age seca1 chad1  DL alog1 dig1 scifirst1 crimetech1
1   F  20  1754  1750 175    95   95       432        429
2   F  19  1594  1596 158    56   55       420        417
3   F  20  1556  1558 156    74   72       435        437
4   F  18  1648  1640 167    67   65       431        434
5   F  19  1780  1780 178    99   67       433        431
6   F  19  1610  1620 165    56   54       423        425
```

After doing this as @janos suggested:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2) / 2 / length(x))}
```

now, as i need to run `f1` on `data_1$alog1` vs `data_1$dig1`... here's what i did:

```
f1(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
```

which gives: `4.3`

Next, I tried to implement the 2nd formula like this:

```
f2 <- function(x, y){(f1 / ((x + y) / 2)) * 100}
```

but then, when I run it on `data_1$alog1` vs `data_1$dig1` to calculate the coefficient of variation of the error for these data I get:

```
> f2(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
Error in f1/((x + y)/2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Could anyone please comment on the steps performed to create the first function, the second function and the way i run the functions on "alog1 vs dig1" ?

Thanks all!!

Comment: You are asking for the best way to do this without showing any attempt in your side to do it! looks like a homework! We are not here to do your job!

Comment: in fact it is a homework!! but im not asking you to do it for me!!
I have no idea why are you attacking me right now... Im just asking for help! If you cannot/ don't want to help me, you are not forced to do otherwise!

Comment: @joran
I have edited the question 13 hours ago, but it still appears on hold.
Is there a way for it to be opened again? or should i create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here you go:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2) / 2 / length(x))
}
f1(1:3, 4:6)
```

This will output:

```
[1] 2.12132
```

The function assumes that `x` and `y` are both vectors of the same length.

You can do the same for the 2nd function, with some simplification:

```
f2 <- function(x, y) {
  200 * f1(x, y) / (x + y)
}
f2(1:3, 3:5)
```

To check that two vectors have the same length, you can use the `length` method. It can be also useful to halt execution if this assumption fails, like this:

```
stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
```

Comment: hey janos, thanks for your help man!
I have a question about the length. what doe it mean in r?
as you assumed both vectors have the same length... where to look in order to know they are of the same length? 
thanks again.

Comment: Thanks man! your answer is helpful and it worked. 
I just would like some more feedback on the steps performed to solve this.