# How to create these functions in R?

Tags: r, function, formula

I have two mathematical formulae that needed to be created as R functions and then run them on my data.

First of all let me show you the head of my data, which I named it "data_1"

```
  sex age seca1 chad1  DL alog1 dig1 scifirst1 crimetech1
1   F  20  1754  1750 175    95   95       432        429
2   F  19  1594  1596 158    56   55       420        417
3   F  20  1556  1558 156    74   72       435        437
4   F  18  1648  1640 167    67   65       431        434
5   F  19  1780  1780 178    99   67       433        431
6   F  19  1610  1620 165    56   54       423        425
```

**Now lets look at the formulae and my attempts to create the functions on r :**

**1)The 1st formula (f1):**

The first formula (can be accessed through [this link](http://i39.tinypic.com/110vfk6.jpg)):

This is what I did to create the first formula:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2) / 2 / length(x))}
```

As I need to run `f1` on `data_1$alog1` vs `data_1$dig1`... here's what I did:

```
f1(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
```

which gives: `4.3`

Now the question is: have I created the function correctly? and is it supposed to be giving me only one value?

**2)The 2nd formula (f2):**

The second function is to create a mathematical formula in which the first function is substituted. Here is the formula --> (follow [this link](http://i43.tinypic.com/b6vq5j.jpg)):

**"f1"** that appears in red in the second formula, is supposed to be the first function created (1st formula).

Next, here is what I did to implement the 2nd formula:

```
f2 <- function(x, y){(f1 / ((x + y) / 2)) * 100}
```

but then, when I run it on `data_1$alog1` vs `data_1$dig1` to calculate the coefficient of variation of the error for these data, I get:

```
> f2(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
Error in f1/((x + y)/2) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Could anyone please comment on the steps performed to create the functions and the way I run the functions on "alog1 vs dig1"?

Comment: I already answered to all of these points in my answer to your original question. Maybe you didn't see my updates? Look closely, it should be all there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824792/creating-functions-to-calculate-the-technical-error-and-the-coefficient-of-varia/20824952#20824952

Comment: please fix the question title - it says nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is a vector, then `sum(x)` is a scalar. To get cumulative sums, use `cumsum(x)`:

```
f1 <- function(x, y) {sqrt(cumsum((x - y) ^ 2) / 2 / length(x))}
f1(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
```

which returns

```
[1] 0.0000000 0.2886751 0.6454972 0.8660254 9.2781104 9.2960565
```

instead of simply returning the last value.
In the second function definition, you are forgetting that `f1` is a function of `(x, y)`:

```
f2 <- function(x, y) {f1(x, y) / ((x + y) / 2) * 100}
f2(data_1$alog1, data_1$dig1)
[1]  0.0000000  0.5201354  0.8842428  1.3121597 11.1784463 16.9019209
```